# Media keys not passing after upgrade to 16.04

Tags: upgrade, 16.04, keyboard, media-buttons

All works bench after upgrade from Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 to 16.04 using `do-release-upgrade`. shell settings, steam games, coding IDEs, databases, vboxes, nodejs/nginx servers and others...

But media keys from my Microsoft keyboard does not passing. Reset values in `gnome-control-center keyboard` has no effect. When I try to set value from keyboard -- key events not passing. But `sudo showkey` handles all keys (https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMSOc.png):

showkey:

```
vasiliy0s@0sserver$ LANG=C sudo showkey
[sudo] password for vasiliy0s: 
kb mode was ?UNKNOWN?
[ if you are trying this under X, it might not work
since the X server is also reading /dev/console ]

press any key (program terminates 10s after last keypress)...
keycode  28 release
keycode 114 press
keycode 114 release
keycode 115 press
keycode 115 release
keycode 113 press
keycode 113 release
```

lsusb:

```
vasiliy0s@0sserver:~$ lsusb | grep Microsoft
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 045e:0745 Microsoft Corp. Nano Transceiver v1.0 for Bluetooth


lsb_release:

vasiliy0s@0sserver:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Comment: Please run `LANG=C sudo showkey`. Not everyone can read Russian here.

Comment: ```
vasiliy0s@0sserver:~$ LANG=C sudo showkey
[sudo] password for vasiliy0s: 
kb mode was ?UNKNOWN?
[ if you are trying this under X, it might not work
since the X server is also reading /dev/console ]

press any key (program terminates 10s after last keypress)...
keycode  28 release
keycode 114 press
keycode 114 release
keycode 115 press
keycode 115 release
keycode 113 press
keycode 113 release
```

Comment: I have check with `acpi_listen` and view 

   `button/volumedown VOLDN 00000080 00000000 K
   button/volumeup VOLUP 00000080 00000000 K`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Why it happens?

The reason is the file `/lib/udev/rules.d/51-these-are-not-joysticks-rm.rules`, which [was added to the Debian package on January 2016](https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/collab-maint/joystick.git/commit/?id=7b3b6758bbfcfe32372c35a4f2ce9d978a9c97fb) as requested in [Debian bug #714399](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=714399) and released as version 1.4.9-1.

*Wait, this is Ubuntu, not Debian!* — Yes, but the [Ubuntu package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/xenial/joystick) is based on the debian one.

However, it was later discovered that [multimedia keys from Microsoft keyboard got disabled](https://github.com/denilsonsa/udev-joystick-blacklist/issues/11). I suspect this happened because of some change in udev or in the kernel between Ubuntu 15.10 and 16.04. I know this because I wrote that file and it worked fine in 15.10, but the bug only happened in 16.04.

Today (August), I finally [updated the repository with the fix](https://github.com/denilsonsa/udev-joystick-blacklist/commit/120eebd2fcb7231083b29b45bc90c8a7a7248cbf) (even though [the fix was proposed in May](https://github.com/denilsonsa/udev-joystick-blacklist/issues/11#issuecomment-216290850)). This fix will be added to the Debian and Ubuntu packages sometime in the future.

Want to learn even more about it? Look at the [udev-joystick-blacklist project on GitHub](https://github.com/denilsonsa/udev-joystick-blacklist/). (Disclaimer: I created that project.)

### How to fix it?

#### Option 1 (the lazy one)

Just wait until an update to the `joystick` package is released.

#### Option 2 (the non-gamer one)

You can just remove that blacklist file:

```
sudo rm /lib/udev/rules.d/51-these-are-not-joysticks-rm.rules
```

Whenever the package gets updated or reinstalled, the file should be recreated.

#### Option 3 (the gamer one)

You can manually update that file with [a new version from the repository](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/denilsonsa/udev-joystick-blacklist/master/51-these-are-not-joysticks-rm.rules). However, pay attention to updates to the `joystick` package. I'm not sure if any update will just overwrite the file, or if the update will ask for the user to merge the file.

Comment: Thanks!!! I just purged `joystick` package and it works! WIthout reboot, just only reconnect the dongle!

Comment: I becuase I use gamepad with Steam, I also reinstall `joystick` package and manually upgrade rules file.